# SQL Server - Validate Column In Every Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core

I am writing a .net core 2.2 C#, code-first, api with a SQL Server backend. It was just requested to make the api a multi-tenant api. So, I added TenantId (INT NOT NULL) to all DB tables, QueryFilters, etc... Everything is working as expected.

I want to ensure I did not and no one in the future will forget to add the TenantId on all inserts. TenantId will always be a value greater than zero. Is there a way in SQL Server to ensure that every insert on every table has a TenantId value that is greater than zero?

Comment: You said you added `TenantId(int not null)`. Did you add that directly to the DB? You know you're gonna need to add that column and a check constraint through EF migrations...or you're gonna hork up your upgradability in the field.

Comment: @Clay - I did not add that directly to the DB. I added through code.

Comment: While you're solution would work, not every table needs to have the tenant ID. You could stick to having a few tables having it and the relationships that those tables map to as a foreign key are implicitly mapped to a specific tenant. For example, if you have a School (as tenant) with Students (mapped to a school) if each student took a class, by default those classes could be inferred to belong to a specific tenant without the ID.

Comment: @Adam -  See comment about FK on accepted answer. Since I already have a tenantId on every table and everything coded is working, do you see any benefit to removing the tenantId from the "Students" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems  that `TenantId` should be a ForeignKey to the table Tenant. If yes then it definitely cannot be zero or less, else :

Add [CHECK Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms179491(v=sql.105)) on the column

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    TenantId INT NOT NULL CHECK(TenantId > 0)
    ...
)
```

And if column is `NOT NULL` then it should be in every insert else exception will throw

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TenantId', table
>   'dbo.your_table'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

Then, in your C# code use Data Annotations attribute

```
[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
```

or create own like: `[MinValue(1)]`

To "ensure that every insert on every table has a TenantId value that is greater than zero" you can also use constructor with private setter

```
public class Model
{
   public Model(int name, int tenantId)
   {
      Name = name;
      if(tenantId <= 0)
      {
          throw new Exception();
      }
      TenantId = tenantId;
   }

   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public int TenantId { get; private set; }
}
```

or something like this property in your model

```
public int TenantId {
    get {
        return _tenantId;
    }
    set {
        if (value <= 0) throw new Exception();
        _tenantId = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: In a code-first EF world?

Comment: And what is the problem with code-first? You can use data annotations or add check on property or use constructors with private setter, it depends on your implementation

Comment: This does answer my question as I stated it. Thanks! Although, the next thing I lookup or ask will be how to add a constraint in entity framework.

Comment: The data annotation [Range(1, int.MaxValue)] is working for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben should not be the TenantId added as ForeignKey to the table Tenant? If yes then it definitely cannot be zero or less

Comment: There is a separate Tenant database that houses all the tenant info. So, making it a FK can't happen. In the startup of my application, I get the tenant Id from a tenant api based upon the api key used to make the request.